# Display number of hours

Tags: vba, time, listbox

I've been trying to find a way to show on a listbox the number of hours between time a and time b, even if thats hundred of hours.
Note: tiempoa was taken with "now" too, obviously before time b.

```
Dim tiempoa As Date
Dim tiempob As Date
Dim tiempoc As Date

tiempoa = .Offset(, -18).Value
tiempob = Now
tiempoc = Format(tiempoa - tiempob, "hh:mm")

Data(i, 5) = tiempoc
```

[This is whats displayed, even it showld be around 80 hours.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX9eS.jpg)

Comment: I answered this in the comments the last time you asked: change the format to "[h]:mm".

Comment: Doesnt work @DougGlancy
Im also trying this;
    tiempoa = .Offset(, -18).Value
                                tiempob = Now
                                tiempoc = DateDiff(hhh, tiempoa, tiempob)

                    Data(i, 5) = tiempoc

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out.

```
   tiempoa = .Offset(, -18).Value
   tiempob = Now
   tiempoc = DateDiff("h", tiempoa, tiempob)

Data(i, 5) = tiempoc
```